# What's happening inside Scikit-Learn's Pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm reading Scikit-Learn's Pipeline section from "Hands-on machine learning with Scikit-Learn and Tensorflow". The book gives explanation about Pipeline as follows

> When you call the pipeline’s fit() method, it calls fit_transform()
>   sequentially on all transformers, passing the output of each call as
>   the parameter to the next call, until it reaches the final estimator,
>   for which it just calls the fit() method

And I'm trying to infer from the text how Pipeline actually works inside Python.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

num_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', Imputer(strategy="median")),
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
])

result = num_pipeline.fit(data)
result
```

At first, I thought this is what's going inside Python:

1. Create an instance of `Imputer(strategy="median")`, which is `imputer`
2. Do `imputer.fit_transform(data)` and return the object to the input of `std_scaler.fit` method, where `std_scaler` is an instance of `StandardScaler()`
3. Return `self` (in this case std_scalar) since `fit` method returns `self`

But the output is,

```
Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('imputer', Imputer(axis=0, copy=True, missing_values='NaN', strategy='median', verbose=0)), ('std_scaler', StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True))])
```

What's happening inside Pipeline?

Comment: Did you run it? If it ran, then that's how it works...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I've just ran it. Got unexpected result..

Comment: In a pipeline, the input data goes to first transformer, which is transformed by it (after fitting) and then goes to the next transformer and so on. When `pipeline.fit()` is called, this process continues till the last transformer, which is only fitted with the data passed from previous one. The `self` returned by the pipeline is the pipeline object itself with all transformers fitted with the data.Think on if it happened to be the last transformer as you suggested it would be, then how will `pipeline.transform()` or `pipeline.predict()` work?